# Delete a member array correctly in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management

In the class that I am in, refactoring the destructor does not manage destroying its array.

```
    class MyClass{
    public:
        double a;
        double rect[4];

        MyClass();
        ~MyClass();
    };

    MyClass::MyClass() : a(123.0)
    {
        memset(rect, 0, 4 * sizeof(double));
    }

    MyClass::~MyClass() {}
```

How do I destroy it correctly? Is a simple `delete` enough or do I also need to set the following afterwards?

```
delete[] rect;
*rect= NULL;
```

Comment: You do nothing, it's not dynamically allocated.

Comment: It seems you are learning C++ from a subpar source (any decent source would have made you sharply aware of how this works in C++ by the time it introduces `delete`). If you are interested we keep [a curated list of nice books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: And while I'm on it, I would advise against `memset` as it is needlessly error-prone; you should be using `std::fill` with `std::begin` and `std::end` (if your compiler is not up-to-date, these last two are easy to implement: https://gist.github.com/rmartinho/3959946).

Comment: What @R.MartinhoFernandes said. But in this case, filling the array with zeros in the body of the constructor isn't even needed. `MyClass::MyClass() : a(123.0), rect() {}` will do nicely.

Comment: @MartinoFernandes: Thank you for the advice. I'm using VC11, but this code is very old.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you need to delete what you new-ed. The `rect` array has the same storage as the enclosing object, so it will be taken care by the process of deleting/leaving the scope where the whole object was allocated.

Comment: "automatic storage" means, roughly, stack-allocated. The `rect` member of a `MyClass` object has the same storage class as the `MyClass` object itself -- which depends on how the `MyClass` object was created. But your main point is correct: destroying the enclosing object will take care of destroying the `rect` member.

Answer (score 2):

You need not do anything as it is allocated on automatic storage rather than dynamic memory. Just a general rule:

1. If you have used `new` to allocate memory, you need to use `delete`.
2. If you have used `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` then you may use `free()`. (Always try using new and delete in C++.)

Comment: It's not allocated on the stack unless it is allocated on the stack.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a3b1d94b9b66f899824da862e468c630-d6c803482d553f395422ddf5510f4bb0

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes so it should be automatic storage and dynamic memory?? correct?? and not stack and heap

Comment: That is better, and I think it's not necessary to be more pedantic (to be excruciatingly accurate would be more confusing than helpful IMO) :) The important bit is that it is not at all about the location but about the duration, and thinking of it in terms of location is misleading (so I am all for expunging the words "stack" and "heap" from discussions on this matter).

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to destroy it, because you haven't created it by your own. As you don't get its memory by `malloc()` or `new`, you don't have to `free()` or `delete` it. It's an automatic identifier. It's just on the automatic memory. That means it's freed/deleted with the process itself anyway.

Comment: As I mentioned in another answer, the stack is irrelevant (and it's actually a lie to claim the array is on the stack: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a3b1d94b9b66f899824da862e468c630-d6c803482d553f395422ddf5510f4bb0)

Comment: @ R. Martinho Fernandes well, I'm sorry about publishing wrong knowledge. But I didn't knew it better. could you explain it to me plz? My point of knew was, all thats allocated automaticly is stored in the stack. But probabl thats wrong, as you guide me to correct it.

Comment: It's simple. Just forget about the location and focus on the lifetime (the automatic vs dynamic part). The location does not dictate anything here. You can have stuff like that array on the heap and still don't have to deallocate it yourself, and you can also have stuff on the stack that you have to deallocate yourself.